# "Order by" in DynamoDB using params

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm not understanding by reading Amazon DynamoDB guide if there's a way to order Items after a query/scan.

For example:

--My database table--

```
        TableName:"Projects",
           Item:{
              "projectOwner": "User1",
              "projectName": "Project1",
              "creationDate": "Wed Nov 20 2016",
              "updateDate": "Wed Nov 29 2016",
         }Item:{
              "projectOwner": "User1",
              "projectName": "Project2",
              "creationDate": "Wed Nov 20 2016",
              "updateDate": "Wed Nov 28 2016",
         }Item:{
              "projectOwner": "User1",
              "projectName": "Project3",
              "creationDate": "Wed Nov 20 2016",
              "updateDate": "Wed Nov 30 2016",
         }
```

So I want to scan my database and return all the Items ordered by "updateDate". Is there a way to achieve this using dynamoDB params?

```
        params = {
             TableName: "Projects",
             ProjectionExpression: "projectName",
             KeyConditionExpression: "projectOwner = :userId",
             ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                 ":userId":userId
             }
        };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `Order By` in DynamoDB. You have to sort the result set at client side if the attribute is not defined as Sort key.

However, if the `updateDate` is defined as Sort key, the API has the feature to sort the data by ascending or descending order.

> If ScanIndexForward is true, DynamoDB returns the results in the order
>   in which they are stored (by sort key value). This is the default
>   behavior. If ScanIndexForward is false, DynamoDB reads the results in
>   reverse order by sort key value, and then returns the results to the
>   client.
>
> Specifies the order for index traversal: If true (default), the
>   traversal is performed in ascending order; if false, the traversal is
>   performed in descending order.

Comment: Hey, so what did you define PK with Sort Key ?