# How to ORDER BY a query in DynamoDB using PartiQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

There are some answers in some forums about this question where people are generally repeating the already confusing AWS documentation about DynamoDB, but I need an example to see how it actually works.
I have this query :

```
SELECT id, message, created, FROM "messages"."sender_company_id-index" 
WHERE sender_company_id = 435634652 AND receiver_company_id = 69992528 
AND sender_user_id = 186 AND receiver_user_id = 201
ORDER BY id DESC
```

and it fails with this error message:

> An error occurred during the execution of the command.
> ValidationException: Variable reference id in ORDER BY clause must be
> part of the primary key

created field is already indexed so what's wrong? Why does it require it to be "part of the primary key"? I would like to order by different fields in different cases so I cant have all of them set as primary key. I dont get it!

**EDIT**

I noticed some of the comments below state that ORDER BY is not a possibility using PartiQL. Also [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888996/order-by-in-dynamodb-using-params) claims that.
However, [AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html) states the opposite.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to make it work though not completely.

```
SELECT id, created, sender_company_id, receiver_company_id
       sender_user_name, sender_user_id, sender_company_name, receiver_company_name
       FROM "messages"."sender_company_id-created-index" 
       WHERE (sender_company_id = 435634652 OR receiver_company_id= 435634652)
       AND (sender_user_id = 186 OR receiver_user_id = 186) 
       ORDER BY created ASC, sender_company_id ASC
```

Error:

> ValidationException: Must have at least one non-optional hash key
> condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause.

If I change the WHERE to this it works:

```
...WHERE sender_company_id = 435634652
```

Here is my indexes:

[image: Screenshot of indexes in AWS]

It is beyond my understanding what's going on here. I do have the indexes, I am using non-optional (key partitions) in the WHERE clause but it fails.

Comment: DynamoDB supports a subset of PartiQL features. It is not, and does not claim to be, fully-featured SQL support, able to execute arbitrary SQL queries. It is gated by the underlying features of DynamoDB (such as query/scan and item ordering). You cannot ORDER BY arbitrary attributes, as you've seen. You cannot ORDER BY without also having a valid WHERE clause, for example.

Comment: Upon further testing - i was able to duplicate this issue. I am checking with the team

Comment: I checked with the team and this is intended functionality. They will be making a doc update too

Comment: What is the Partition Key and Sort Key of the `sender_company_id-index` index?

Comment: @fedonev a partition key of sender_company_id-index ? How can you even make a partition key for an index? I already set the partition key when created the table, and it is "id"

Comment: @smac2020 Is there any way to accomplish ORDER BY using PartiQL?

Comment: @jarmod So, there is no way to ORDER BY using partiql?

Comment: When you create a GSI, you provide a partition key and an optional sort key, just like when you created the base table. A GSI is an index with a different partition key than the one on the base table. A GSI can have a simple or composite primary key. Think of a GSI as another table, if you like, that has a different partitioning scheme.

Comment: @jarmod when you create a GSI, that partition key is it a field of the table right?

Comment: It can be any attribute you like, even one that doesn't currently appear in any item of the table. All items that contain a matching attribute will be indexed in the GSI.

Comment: @jarmod can you take a look at the example posted below by fedonev where he is creating a GSI with a partition key that doesnt exist GSI1PK and a sort key that doesnt exists GSI1SK and then he ORDERS BY Sort key (SK) ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "he is creating a GSI with a partition key that doesnt exist GSI1PK". The partition key of the example GSI1 index is the attribute GSI1PK, and the sort key is the attribute GSI1SK. They *do* exist in the example item, though they are not part of the base table's composite index (and they don't have to be).

Comment: BTW you didn't answer the earlier question from @fedonev about the pk/sk of the sender_company_id-index, but from the naming I am assuming that it has a pk of sender_company_id and it has no sk.

Comment: @jarmod I mean how do you order by some field if that field does not exist in the table? That makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @jarmod I made a working example, please check the update. I have another problem now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245298/discussion-between-jarmod-and-showtime).

Answer (score 3):

###### [EDIT: OP added index key details and a second PartiQL statement]

Error #1 is happening because you can only `ORDER BY` a field that is the `sender_company_id-index` index's Partition (=Hash) Key or Sort (=Range) Key<sup>*</sup>.  See the first block of unhappy examples marked ❌.  Error #2 is happening because `ORDER BY` seems to be supported only for query operations (your second statement is a scan). This constraint makes sense, but I could not find it documented anywhere.  See the second block of unhappy ❌ examples.  But first, some working `ORDER BY` examples:

> I need an example to see how it actually works.

`my-table` has a Partition Key `PK` and Sort Key `SK`.  The table has one secondary index, named `GSI1`. The index uses the `GSI1PK` field as its Partition Key and its Sort Key is `GSI1SK`.  Here's a sample record:

```json
{
 "PK": "1x", "SK": "cc", "GSI1PK": "a", "GSI1SK": "b1", "Other": "foo", "Another": "bar"
}
```

These are valid PartiQL `ORDER BY` statements:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "my-table"        WHERE PK = '1x'                              ORDER BY SK     ASC
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."GSI1" WHERE GSI1PK = 'a'                           ORDER BY GSI1SK ASC
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."GSI1" WHERE GSI1PK IN ['a', 'b']                   ORDER BY GSI1PK DESC, GSI1SK ASC
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."GSI1" WHERE GSI1PK IN ['a', 'b']                   ORDER BY GSI1SK DESC, GSI1PK DESC
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."GSI1" WHERE GSI1PK IN ['a', 'b'] AND Other = 'foo' ORDER BY GSI1SK DESC, GSI1PK DESC
```

However, ordering by fields other than the Primary Keys *of the index I'm querying on* will fail:

```sql
-- ValidationException: Variable reference Other in ORDER BY clause must be part of the primary key
❌ SELECT * FROM "my-table"."GSI1" WHERE GSI1PK = 'a' ORDER BY Other ASC
-- ValidationException: Variable reference GSI1PK in ORDER BY clause must be part of the primary key
❌ SELECT * FROM "my-table" WHERE PK = 'a' ORDER BY GSI1PK ASC
```

`ORDER BY` apparently also requires a `WHERE` clause with a `=` or `IN` condition on the Partition Key.  That is, ordering succeeds for [query operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html#ql-reference.select.parameters). Scan operations with ordering fail:

```sql
-- ValidationException: Must have WHERE clause in the statement when using ORDER BY clause.
❌ SELECT * FROM "my-table" ORDER BY SK ASC

-- ValidationException: Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause.
❌ SELECT * FROM "my-table" WHERE begins_with(PK, 'b') ORDER BY SK ASC
```

> the created field is already indexed so what's wrong?

DynamoDB [secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.SecondaryIndexes) are fundamentally different than their RDBMS cousins.  *A secondary index lets you query the data in the table using an [alternate key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general.html).*

> Why does it require it to be "part of the primary key"? I would like to order by different fieldds

DynamoDB imposes design constraints to preserve its scalability superpowers.

---

* You can only order by the primary key elements of your statement's `table[.index]`, as in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html): `SELECT ... FROM table[.index] ORDER BY key [DESC|ASC]`, where `key` is a  *"hash key or a sort key to use to order returned results."*

Comment: ok, still confusing. In the first example you took, it seems like you can order by using primary key which in my case in "id". And I did try to order by using id field, it still shows the same error.

Comment: I got it now, I just added an index in one of the fields and a sort key to created field. I am now able to order by created unix timestamp. Thats all I needed to know.

Comment: I have a simple question, should I create indexes for all fields that I use in WHERE clauses?

Comment: When you say "...The table has one secondary index, named GSI1. The index has a Partition Key GSI1PK and Sort Key GSI1SK" what do you actually mean??? How can you actually create an index with partition key of a field that doesn't even exist GSI1PK ?! Shouldn't the partition key be PK and sort key SK and then name the index as you wish? Please explain

Comment: Read [General Guidelines for Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general.html).  Becoming a DynamoDB Master is like becoming a Jedi Master.  You must forget what you know about RDBMS and embrace [DynamoDB NoSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html).  As Yoda said to Luke: _"Always with you what cannot be done. Hear you nothing that I say?… You must unlearn what you have learned."_   Feel the Force, @showtime!

Comment: thanks, i will go through them. I just believe the examples you took are actually wrong.

Comment: In terms of learning the intricacies of DynamoDB, read everything you can by [Alex DeBrie](https://github.com/alexdebrie/awesome-dynamodb).

Comment: @showtime My examples use the DynamoDB [generic key name pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html). I ran all the examples in a live table.  But if you find an error, let me know!

Comment: @fedonev can you please take an example using the naming I provided in the query I posted? In the examples you took you are sorting by a sort key which is not in the index nor sort key.